# Configure Spring Data Flow with RabbitMQ - Connection refused (Connection refused)

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to run spring dataflow local server and configure rabbitmq binder for all applications. I have rabbitmq running on docker on host 172.17.0.2.

```
java -jar spring-cloud-dataflow-server-local-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar 
--spring.cloud.dataflow.applicationProperties.stream.spring.cloud.stream.binders.rabbit1.type=rabbit 
--spring.cloud.dataflow.applicationProperties.stream.spring.cloud.stream.binders.rabbit1.environment.spring.rabbit.host=172.17.0.2 
--spring.cloud.dataflow.applicationProperties.stream.spring.cloud.stream.binders.rabbit1.environment.spring.rabbit.user=guest 
--spring.cloud.dataflow.applicationProperties.stream.spring.cloud.stream.binders.rabbit1.environment.spring.rabbit.password=guest
```

Exception

```
{
"timestamp": 1502479027168,
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"exception": "org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException",
"message": "error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.integration.amqp.outbound.AmqpOutboundEndpoint@45e29e0]; nested exception is org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)",
"path": "/"
}
```

Spring Data Flow can't find RabbitMQ.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if there is a typo in your properties. Instead of `applicationProperties.stream.spring.cloud.stream.binders.rabbit1.environment.spring.rabbit.host=172.17.0.2`, it should be
`applicationProperties.stream.spring.cloud.stream.binders.rabbit1.environment.spring.rabbitmq.host=172.17.0.2`.

It needs to be `spring.rabbitmq.host`. Same is true for the other two properties.

Answer (score 0):

**There's one more aspect to the problem.**

By default, the RabbitMQ is accessible to the local machine only. If you want to access it from some other machine, you generally create one entry in "**rabbitmq.config**" file. Location of this file varies from OS to OS.

1. In Linux, you can find this at: "/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config"
2. In Windows machine, you can find it at: "C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.6.9\etc\rabbitmq.config".

There's a possibility that you ***don't find*** this file at the mentioned location. This is an *optional* file and you need not to worry if it is missing even. You can create your own. This entry is something like:

```
[{rabbit, [{tcp_listeners, [{"<IP_OF_MACHINE>", 5672}]},{loopback_users, []}]}].
```

With this, you can access the server from any remote machine.

If after this you get the server inaccessible you can modify the entry to:

```
[{rabbit, [{tcp_listeners, [{"0.0.0.0", 5672}]},{loopback_users, []}]}].
```

You will **definitely** get the server connected to any client as well as through management console (if plugin enabled)